# Difference between SCOPE_SINGLETON and private constructor

Tags: java, spring

what is the difference between SCOPE_SINGLETON and private constructor?
After initialized any class with SCOPE_SINGLETON, i am able to create object also.

Error:-

> Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class utility: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class utility

First i want to clear that i was not making object using new operator. i used @Component and private constructor. it was working fine. but when i upgrade our sb 1.5 to sb2.0 with gradle upgrade to 4.1. Sonar was start giving me this error. then i removed private constructor and added scope_singleton. it worked for me. even i removed @Component and added throw in my private const. it worked. that's why i asked, what is difference b/w scope_singleton and private constructor.

Working Code:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class utility1 {
}
```

Error Code:

```
@Component
public class utility2 {
    private utility2() {
    }
}
```

Comment: These are two unrelated concepts. It's unclear in what context you're trying to compare them.

Comment: Added error in my original post

Comment: looks like, nobody is understand my question. anyway thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Spring is a framework here you are focusing on the part of the deoendency injection.
By default, the components in Spring are singletons, you do not need to specify that it is a scope_singleton.
Spring does have requirements for its components and one of them is to have a visible constructor (otherwise, spring is not able to create them, so making a public constructor should work for you).
It wiol be a Singleton for Spring as Spring will manage only one instance, but using new you can create as much as you want (I rather think is not a good idea)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Spring framework you shouldn't try to create annotated classes with `new` operator or somehow else. Only Spring core should be responsible for bean class creation and only in this situation you could be sure that your class is really singleton etc.

Comment: Agree to your point. I was not creating class with new. but sonar was given me error while declare class with private constructor. then i changed to @Scope. it was resolved. i wanted to know , how internally it works.

Comment: Added error in my original post for your reference.